# PerformancePoint and Sharepoint list as a data source

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint

I was asked to create a very simple dashboard using a Sharepoint list as my data source using the Dashboard Designer tool.  I can create the datasource, retrieve the list and see the data in a tabular format.  Now, when I try creating a KPI or a ScoreCard out of that list, I get a 'Unable to retrieve list' error.  Has anybody else run into this?  It doesn't seem to be a connection or a permission issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you been through the [MSDN Virtual Lab on Performance Point](http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/itprotips/archive/2008/02/20/microsoft-office-performance-point-server-2007-sharepoint-list-dashboards.aspx)? It has a complete walkthrough of creating a list and configuring the dashboard to talk to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tom. Yes, I actually follow through the Virtual Lab. The problem I was having was related to the internal configuration of our Sharepoint server. I was also missing the service account access on the Sharepoint server.